# to print two text using split before hypen

Tags: python, split

I want to print the text/string before hypen.My text is

```
060713-2-29-1_vstrot_105-15
```

I have tried

```
out_string = ",".join([str(imgstr.split('-')[0:2])])
print(out_string)
```

But the output is

```
['060713', '2']
```

I need the output without brackets and with a hypen using split

```
060713-2
```

Comment: ``split`` return's list those brackets indicate its of type list, you can do join ``'-'.join(['060713', '2'])`` to convert back to string.

Comment: @Sushanth actually i want it in a single line code as I am using it to make excel file and i want to remove brackets too

Comment: You can use regex in that case, ``import re; re.search('(\d+-\d)-', '060713-2-29-1_vstrot_105-15').group(1)``

Comment: Just use `"-".join(imgstr.split('-')[:2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imgstr = '060713-2-29-1_vstrot_105-15'
out_string = "-".join(imgstr.split('-')[0:2])
print(out_string)
```

```
060713-2
```

`split` return an array, you don't have to convert it to string as you are using `join` after that.

`join` will take everything in your array (for us first 2 elements as we are saying `0:2`) and create a string by combining the elements with `-` while you are using `,` which is not needed